# How do I set images to listview items when they contain certain text?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, listview, imagelist

Does anyone know how I set images to [listview](/questions/tagged/listview) items when they contain certain text? For instance if an items' text is something with ".png" I want to give that item (or those items) an image which I've added to an [imagelist](/questions/tagged/imagelist).  
Here is the code I use to populate the [listview](/questions/tagged/listview) with folders and files:

```
    Dim FilePath As String = "C:\"
    ControlListView.Items.Clear()
    Dim DirInfo() As DirectoryInfo

    DirInfo = New DirectoryInfo(FilePath).GetDirectories

    For Each DirInfoFolder In DirInfo
        ControlListView.Items.Add(DirInfoFolder.Name)
    Next

    Dim FilePathFiles As New IO.DirectoryInfo(FilePath)

    For Each FileInfoFolder In FilePathFiles.GetFiles
        ControlListView.Items.Add(FileInfoFolder.Name)
    Next
```

Any help would be appriciated. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: use the `.ImageIndex` property of the `ListViewItem` using the index of the image you want in your ImageList.

Comment: I think you missed something. I need a specific image for every filetype. I already got the images but how do I apply them? (When a listview item contains for example .png?)

Comment: *find* the specific image, get the index and *"apply"* it by using the `.ImageIndex` property.  If png is index 13 in your imagelist then use that as the prop val for `myLVI.ImageIndex = x`

Comment: This is not a forum - we dont mark Questions SOLVED.  The checkmark serves that purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the default ListView.Add(string), you need to construct your own ListViewItem and then add it to the ListView after setting the correct index for the image in the image list.  (My VB.Net is rusty so please verify the syntax)

```
For Each FileInfoFolder In FilePathFiles.GetFiles
    Dim lvi as New ListViewItem(FileInfoFolder.Name)

    If FileInfoFolder.Name.EndsWith(".png")
        lvi.ImageIndex = pngImageIndex
    End If

    ControlListView.Items.Add(lvi)
Next
```

Comment: It works, only the problem is, the resolution is poor. The images are 100x100. Tried to change the size within the ImageList without a result. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: where do you get the pngImageIndex @cdkMoose ?

Comment: @gumuruh, from wherever you keep your list of images.  You would get this from identifying the desired image in your ImageList.  Likely you would store the image index for .png, .pdf, ... instead of constantly looking it up